# How are people who write introductions and afterwords credited?

Tags: creative-writing, introduction

Sorry for the naive nature of this question.

I'm writing a story with a deceased fictional author, and one of his living relatives writes an introduction and afterword explaining the context of the story.

This got me thinking: How are people in real life credited when they write an introduction, preface, etc?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their name appears at the end of the foreword, they're often in the author's acknowledgements, and if they're more famous than the author, often on the cover blurb. But their name at the end of the foreword is the only thing that's 'necessary' (and consistent).

They do not  appear in citations in APA or MLA formats - there may be more arcane citation styles that they do, but I've never heard of it.